# build.gradle - Configure Eclipse so that System.getenv('PATH') returns the same value as from command line in macOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, gradle, environment-variables, buildship

The environment:

- macOS 10.15.7
- Gradle 6.8.2
- Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)

The problem:

I have a very simple Gradle build script that works from the command line but fails when running within Eclipse.
I have boiled it down to the fact that System.getenv('PATH') returns 2 different values depending on gradle being run from command line or from eclipse
I have created a very simple gradle build that only contains:

```
 tasks.register('debug') {
 doLast {
     println System.getenv('PATH')
 }
```

}

If I run the task from Eclipse, the output is:

```
> Task :debug
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If I run the tasks from the macOS command line the output is:

```
> Task :debug
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

It is clear that Eclipse somehow does not have access to the same PATH as my command line.

So my questions are:

1. Can I force Eclipse to have access to the same PATH environment variable as my command line
2. Can I configure Eclipse to add custom entries to the PATH environment variable
3. Can I configure my Gradle run configuration in Eclipse to add custom entries to the PATH environment variable
4. Can I configure Gradle, in general, to add custom entries to the PATH environment variable

Thanks

Comment: Does [PATH env variable on Mac OS X and/or Eclipse](https://superuser.com/q/28344) help?

Comment: Thanks, but none of the suggested solutions works or fit my needs. I need a solution where any change is only applied to the Eclipse IDE or the Run Configuration of the gradle task inside Eclipse.